# How to write Junit Test cases for GCP PUB/SUB in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, mockito, junit4, publish-subscribe

I want to write Junit test cases for GCP pub/sub but I don't know where to start from. I can't find anything on it. It will be of great help if anyone can help me with it.I'm providing some of my code below.

**Subscriber**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class Subscriber{
     @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "inputMessageChannel")
        public void messageReceiver(
                String payload,
                @Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE) BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage message) {
            log.info("Message arrived via an inbound channel adapter from sub-one! Payload: " + payload);
    
            Map<String, String> attributes = message.getPubsubMessage().getAttributesMap();
            log.info(attributes.toString());
            message.ack();
        }
}
```

**Publisher**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class Publisher {

    @Autowired
    private PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;

    public void publish(String topicName, String message, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        log.info("published to topic " + topicName + " message = " + message);
        pubSubTemplate.publish(topicName, message, attributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use official [Pub/Sub emulator](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) provided by Google.

Emulator can be run manually from CLI as described in doc or you can use [TestContainers GCloud module](https://java.testcontainers.org/modules/gcloud/#pubsub) there is also example use with Spring Boot [repo](https://github.com/saturnism/testcontainers-gcloud-examples/blob/main/springboot/pubsub-example/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/pubsub/PubSubIntegrationTests.java)

If you choose to run it manually you can skip setting environment variables as for Java there is another way of doing it (described in the doc in more details).
Probably you have created your topics and subscriptions by `gcloud pubsub ...` commands, unfortunately emulator do not support these commands so as far as I know you have to create them in your application via SDK.
You can do something like this (kotlin code) to create subscription, topics and publisher that uses emulator.
Then your message channel should pick it.

**PubsubConfigLocalAndTest**

```
@Configuration
@Profile("default || test")
class PubsubConfigLocalAndTest {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this::class.java)

    @Value("\${spring.cloud.gcp.project-id:}")
    lateinit var projectId: String

    @Value("\${spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.emulator-host:}")
    lateinit var hostport: String

    private val credentialsProvider: CredentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create()

    @Bean
    fun testTransportChannelProvider(): TransportChannelProvider {
        val channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build()
        return FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel))
    }

    @Bean
    fun topics(testTransportChannelProvider: TransportChannelProvider): Array<EventTopics> {
        val topicAdminSettings = TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
            .setTransportChannelProvider(testTransportChannelProvider)
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build()

        TopicAdminClient.create(topicAdminSettings).use { topicAdminClient ->
            EventTopics.values().forEach { topic ->
                try {
                    topicAdminClient.createTopic(projectId, topic.name)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    logger.info("Topic not created: ${topic.name}")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        return EventTopics.values()
    }

    @Bean
    fun subscriptions(testTransportChannelProvider: TransportChannelProvider): Array<EventSubscriptions> {
        val subscriptionAdminSettings = SubscriptionAdminSettings.newBuilder()
            .setTransportChannelProvider(testTransportChannelProvider)
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build()

        SubscriptionAdminClient.create(subscriptionAdminSettings).use { subscriptionAdminClient ->
            EventSubscriptions.values().forEach { subscription ->
                try {
                    subscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(projectId, subscription.name)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    logger.info("Subscription not created: ${subscription.name}")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
        return EventSubscriptions.values()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun SubscriptionAdminClient.createSubscription(projectId: String?, subscriptionId: String?): Subscription? {
        val subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.of(projectId, subscriptionId)
        val topicName =
            TopicName.of(projectId, EventSubscriptions.valueOf(subscriptionId!!).getTopic().name)
        val pushConfig = PushConfig.newBuilder().build()
        val response = this.createSubscription(subscriptionName, topicName, pushConfig, 600)
        logger.info("Created subscription: " + response.name)
        return response
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun TopicAdminClient.createTopic(projectId: String?, topicId: String?): Topic? {
        val topicName = TopicName.of(projectId, topicId)
        val topic = this.createTopic(topicName)
        logger.info("Created topic: " + topic.name)
        return topic
    }
}
```

**Publisher for your test should also use emulator**

```
fun getPublisher(
        topicName: TopicName,
        channelProvider: TransportChannelProvider? = null,
        env: Environment? = null
    ): Publisher {
        return if (channelProvider != null && (env?.isLocal() == true || env?.isTest() == true)) {
            Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
                .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
                .setCredentialsProvider(NoCredentialsProvider.create())
                .setEnableMessageOrdering(true)
                .build()
        } else {
            Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).setEnableMessageOrdering(true).build()
        }
    }
```

**application.yml**

```
  cloud:
    gcp:
      project-id: xxx
      pubsub:
        emulator-host: "localhost:8085"
```

I guess instead of creating subscriptions and topics in the config you can build Topic in test case and use SubscriberStub as in [3](https://github.com/saturnism/testcontainers-gcloud-examples/blob/main/springboot/pubsub-example/src/test/java/com/example/springboot/pubsub/PubSubIntegrationTests.java) link.
Another resource I found is the [medium post](https://raphaeldelio.medium.com/how-to-connect-your-spring-cloud-application-to-a-local-google-cloud-pub-sub-emulator-512926cce2b4) but it spring-cloud-stream bindings instead of message channels.

It's a tricky topic and I couldn't find more complicated setup so if you will discover something please comment :)